# Unable to use two database links in a single query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to use two database links in a single query, one for fetching data and the other to insert data. But I'm unable to use them in a single query, even though both of them work perfectly when they are used in separate queries. Can't I use separate database links in a single query and if so why not? The query I'm trying to run is like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1@DBLINK1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2@DBLINK2;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: This looks highly inefficient. Your statement implies the use of 3 different databases to insert into one database. I am wondering why the insert statement is not run directly off the database @dblink1. 
Instead it looks like you are using an intermediate database to run the query between the other two?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The error is ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found.

Comment: @OraNob: I know its inefficient. But the DBlink between the source and destination doesn't exist.

Comment: Does it work if you do `create view v_table2 as select * from table2@dblink2` and then `insert into table1@dblink1 select * from v_table2`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Still not working

Comment: @Nitish - Even if the link doesn't exist you could embed the TNS network settings into the link syntax on the command line.

Comment: This works OK for me in 11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.3 (Linux). What version are you using, for all three databases? Does your real query have a `where` clause, and if so does it link the tables? Does the `insert into` work if you use a `values` clause - you said 'both work perfectly' but don't know if that's just for `select`. There are some bugs in this area so you might be hitting one of those, but not enough detail to suggest a candidate.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your dblink ? SELECT * FROM DBA_DB_LINKS

Comment: @AlexPoole: I'm using Oracle 10.2.0. There is not `where` clause in the query. It works fine if I use a `values` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in 10g. Possibly bug 6320621, ORA-2019 OCCURS WHEN SQL CONNECTS MULTIPLE SITES VIA DBLINK'; or 5713736, 'INSERT INTO STATEMENT WITH SELECT OPTION FAILS USING DB-LINK ORA-02019'. You probably need to raise an SR with Oracle to get this investigated for your specific circumstances.

As an alternative approach, you could maybe consider unloading the data from one database and then loading it into the other. For example, you could use `expdp` and `impdp`, with the `tables` and `content=data_only` options, to do the transfer in two stages. Of course you need space to store the dump file on your intermediate database server, and it's rather less convenient. You might be able to do that form the source or destination database servers, avoiding the intermediate, but it's not clear if you have any direct access.

Comment: When I ran expdb it generated the error  
UDE-00008: operation generated ORACLE error 12560  
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: @Nitish - that's probably a new question, but probably something off in how you're connecting. If your DB link is using a TNS alias then you ought to be able to do `expdp user/password@alias ...`; if not you can use EZConnect, something like `expdp user/password@//server:port/service_name ...`. If it isn't that trivial then you'll need to ask a new question, possibly on [dba.se]. I'm assuming you're familiar with [expdp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm) already.