# Stored Procedure Execution Issue - ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 Oracle 11g databases, let's say DB-1 (CPSBK), DB-2 (ORCL_CC), DB-3 (DRCPSMGT). On CPSBK DB-1 I am logged in using CPSRPTL user and procedure given below is owned by this user.

We have a stored procedure (shown below) that when executed/run, gives following error. Delete statement in this query works perfectly when run separately. So does the SELECT (including UNION ALLs) statement.

But when the insert is tried it throws an error also shown below. I am stuck on this and no help available that I could find online.

Error details when procedure is run:

```
Connecting to the database CPSBK-10.227.23.239-LIVE.
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-02063: preceding line from CPSBK
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from ORCL_CC
ORA-06512: at "CPSRPTL.PRC_MFS_CC_LOAD_DATA", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database CPSBK-10.227.23.239-LIVE.
```

PL/SQL procedure is below (Oracle); this is created on CPSBK (DB-1).

There are two public database links as well in this database, ORCL_CC & DRCPSMGT.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_MFS_CC_LOAD_DATA
AS
BEGIN
  DELETE
  FROM CPS.MFS_CPS_CC_TASKS_REPORT@ORCL_CC
  WHERE data_date = (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'yyyymmdd'));
  INSERT INTO CPS.MFS_CPS_CC_TASKS_REPORT@ORCL_CC
  SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'yyyymmdd') DATA_DATE,
    SYSDATE DATA_INSERTION_TIME,
    ABC.Task_No,
    ABC.Order_ID,
    ABC.Task_Priority,
    ABC.Task_Name,
    ABC.Creation_Hour,
    ABC.Create_Time,
    ABC.Completed_Time,
    ABC.Time_Difference,
    ABC.Initiator_Login,
    ABC.Role_Assigned_Maker,
    ABC.Checker_Login,
    ABC.Role_Assigned_Checker,
    ABC.Task_State,
    ABC.Task_Type,
    ABC.Task_Description
  FROM
    (SELECT t.taskid Task_No,
      T.ORDERID Order_ID,
      DECODE (T.PRIORITY , 50 , 'Low', 100 ,'Medium', 200 , 'High', 'Other') Task_Priority,
      T.TASKNAME Task_Name,
      TO_CHAR(t.createtime, 'HH24') Creation_Hour,
      T.CREATETIME Create_Time,
      T.COMPLETEDTIME Completed_Time,
      (to_timestamp(T.COMPLETEDTIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(T.CREATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ) Time_Difference,
      op1.user_name Initiator_Login,
      RD1.NAME Role_Assigned_Maker,
      op2.user_name Checker_Login,
      RD2.NAME Role_Assigned_Checker,
      T.TASKSTATE Task_State,
      t.tasktype Task_Type,
      T.DESCRIPTION Task_Description
    FROM cpsmgt.cps_tasktodo@DRCPSMGT t
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op1
    ON OP1.OPERATOR_ID = T.createid
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op2
    ON OP2.OPERATOR_ID = T.OWNERID
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO1
    ON op1.operator_id = ro1.operator_id
    AND op1.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD1
    ON RD1.ROLE_ID = RO1.ROLE_ID
    AND RD1.STATUS = '30'
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO2
    ON op2.operator_id = ro2.operator_id
    AND op2.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD2
    ON RD2.ROLE_ID    = RO2.ROLE_ID
    AND RD2.STATUS    = '30'
    WHERE T.TASKSTATE = 'Completed'
    AND T.CREATETIME BETWEEN to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      || ' 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      || ' 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND t.procdefid IN ( 'IC_EditP2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetCustomerPinWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerProductWorkflow', 'IC_EditG2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityStatusWorkflow', 'TC_CancelRemittanceWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPINWorkflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL1Workflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL2Workflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityKYCWorkflow', 'IC_UnblockPaymentTransactionWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPasswordWorkflow' )
    AND rd1.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    AND rd2.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    UNION ALL
    -- Incomplete Orders. from all dates.
    SELECT t.taskid Task_No,
      T.ORDERID Order_ID,
      DECODE (T.PRIORITY , 50 , 'Low', 100 ,'Medium', 200 , 'High', 'Other') Task_Priority,
      T.TASKNAME Task_Name,
      TO_CHAR(t.createtime, 'HH24') Creation_Hour,
      T.CREATETIME Create_Time,
      T.COMPLETEDTIME Completed_Time,
      (to_timestamp(T.COMPLETEDTIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(T.CREATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ) Time_Difference,
      op1.user_name Initiator_Login,
      RD1.NAME Role_Assigned_Maker,
      op2.user_name Checker_Login,
      RD2.NAME Role_Assigned_Checker,
      T.TASKSTATE Task_State,
      t.tasktype Task_Type,
      T.DESCRIPTION Task_Description
    FROM cpsmgt.cps_tasktodo@DRCPSMGT t
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op1
    ON OP1.OPERATOR_ID = T.createid
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op2
    ON OP2.OPERATOR_ID = T.OWNERID
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO1
    ON op1.operator_id = ro1.operator_id
    AND op1.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD1
    ON RD1.ROLE_ID = RO1.ROLE_ID
    AND RD1.STATUS = '30'
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO2
    ON op2.operator_id = ro2.operator_id
    AND op2.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD2
    ON RD2.ROLE_ID     = RO2.ROLE_ID
    AND RD2.STATUS     = '30'
    WHERE T.TASKSTATE <> 'Completed'
    AND T.CREATETIME   < to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      || ' 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND t.procdefid IN ( 'IC_EditP2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetCustomerPinWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerProductWorkflow', 'IC_EditG2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityStatusWorkflow', 'TC_CancelRemittanceWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPINWorkflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL1Workflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL2Workflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityKYCWorkflow', 'IC_UnblockPaymentTransactionWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPasswordWorkflow' )
    AND rd1.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    AND rd2.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.taskid Task_No,
      T.ORDERID Order_ID,
      DECODE (T.PRIORITY , 50 , 'Low', 100 ,'Medium', 200 , 'High', 'Other') Task_Priority,
      T.TASKNAME Task_Name,
      TO_CHAR(t.createtime, 'HH24') Creation_Hour,
      T.CREATETIME Create_Time,
      T.COMPLETEDTIME Completed_Time,
      (to_timestamp(T.COMPLETEDTIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(T.CREATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ) Time_Difference,
      op1.user_name Initiator_Login,
      RD1.NAME Role_Assigned_Maker,
      op2.user_name Checker_Login,
      RD2.NAME Role_Assigned_Checker,
      T.TASKSTATE Task_State,
      t.tasktype Task_Type,
      T.DESCRIPTION Task_Description
    FROM cpsmgt.cps_taskhis@DRCPSMGT t
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op1
    ON OP1.OPERATOR_ID = T.createid
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.CPS_OPERATOR@DRCPSMGT op2
    ON OP2.OPERATOR_ID = T.OWNERID
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO1
    ON op1.operator_id = ro1.operator_id
    AND op1.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD1
    ON RD1.ROLE_ID = RO1.ROLE_ID
    AND RD1.STATUS = '30'
    LEFT JOIN CPSMGT.cps_role_operator@DRCPSMGT RO2
    ON op2.operator_id = ro2.operator_id
    AND op2.status    <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN CPSSYS.CPS_ROLE_DEF@DRCPSMGT RD2
    ON RD2.ROLE_ID = RO2.ROLE_ID
    AND RD2.STATUS = '30'
    WHERE T.CREATETIME BETWEEN to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      || ' 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND to_date(TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
      || ' 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND t.procdefid IN ( 'IC_EditP2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetCustomerPinWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerProductWorkflow', 'IC_EditG2PMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityStatusWorkflow', 'TC_CancelRemittanceWorkflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerMSISDNWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPINWorkflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL1Workflow', 'IC_MigrateCustTrustL2Workflow', 'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityKYCWorkflow', 'IC_UnblockPaymentTransactionWorkflow', 'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPasswordWorkflow' )
    AND rd1.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    AND rd2.name    IN ('Complaints (Maker)','MFS 1344 Help Line','MFS 4444 Helpline','Operator user(back end user) maker', 'Complaints Checker','Operator user(back end user) completer')
    ) ABC
  ORDER BY 1;
  COMMIT;
END PRC_MFS_CC_LOAD_DATA;
```

Target table in `ORCL_CC` database is defined as below:

```
desc CPS.MFS_CPS_CC_TASKS_REPORT@ORCL_CC

Name                  Null Type                         
--------------------- ---- ---------------------------- 
DATA_DATE                  CHAR(8)                      
DATA_INSERTION_TIME        DATE                         
TASK_NO                    VARCHAR2(22)                 
ORDER_ID                   VARCHAR2(22)                 
TASK_PRIORITY              VARCHAR2(6)                  
TASK_NAME                  VARCHAR2(256)                
CREATION_HOUR              VARCHAR2(2)                  
CREATE_TIME                DATE                         
COMPLETED_TIME             DATE                         
TIME_DIFFERENCE            INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(0) 
INITIATOR_LOGIN            VARCHAR2(32)                 
ROLE_ASSIGNED_MAKER        VARCHAR2(100)                
CHECKER_LOGIN              VARCHAR2(32)                 
ROLE_ASSIGNED_CHECKER      VARCHAR2(100)                
TASK_STATE                 VARCHAR2(20)                 
TASK_TYPE                  VARCHAR2(32)                 
TASK_DESCRIPTION           VARCHAR2(1024)
```

Comment: Another Comment from stackoverflow says it seems a bug in Oracle 11g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983378/unable-to-use-two-database-links-in-a-single-query

Comment: @marc_s
Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't see any issue in the procedure, while thinking alternative approach to a seek resolution, how about trying following methods:

1. Can you try checking to put COMMIT in between DELETE AND INSERT?
2. Can see multiple DBLINK used in INSERT block, are you allowed to use sufficient number of open links? Please check open_links and open_links_per_instance(if in RAC) parameters and increase the value if required and try again.
3. Likewise, single statement using MERGE and incorporate DELETE and INSERT block together.

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue by another approach getting to know that it is a known bug from another thread somewhere i don't remember now.

Thank you for your comment. I might not try it though as my issue was resolved.