# Oracle DBlink senseless behavior

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to use two DB links in one query:

```
delete Table1@Link1
where Id in (
    select Id
    from Table2@Link2
);
```

But see following error:

> ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

While these two queries work separately:

```
select * from Table2@Link2;
delete Table1@Link1;
```

All queries in one file with one connection.

Tried to recreate DBLinks, tried make them public, nothing helps. I do know that it should work.

**UPD**: I tried with other tables and found something interesting: I see this strange behavior only if table has at least one CLOB column. Query works fine with tables without CLOB columns. Though I still cannot explain why the query works if I invert the links. For some reason this also works even with CLOB column tables:

```
delete Table2@Link2
where Id in (
    select Id
    from Table1@Link1
);
```

I think it's definitely a bug.

Comment: What's incredibly beautiful, if I swap links in the first query, it works: delete Table2@Link2 where Id in ( select Id from Table1@Link1 ). What a wonderful Oracle world.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? Is this perhaps an Oracle bug as described by [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11983378/409172)

Comment: Version is: 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production. Seems like it's exactly the same bug.

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe this issue is related to the IDE? Some IDEs retrieve the LOB locator (like a pointer), but only return the actual data when you click on the "..." button to show the whole value. Perhaps the IDE is getting confused about which database the pointers point to? To test this theory, try running your test case through SQL\*Plus instead of an IDE. SQL\*Plus is old-fashioned, but it is usually pretty bullet proof when it comes to running SQL correctly. And make sure you use the real SQL\*Plus command line program, not the imitation version from your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which might be useful for someone who encounters the same issue. I ended up creating the same source/destination temp tables with CTAS but casting CLOB into VARCHAR columns. This is only relevant if data in your CLOB columns have length less than 4000 chars, so that's not a complete solution, but worked in my case.

After this step I was able to use DB links to copy large amount of data between DBs without the error. And once finished, just performed INSERT/SELECT from temp table on destination DB, but with a cast from VARCHAR to CLOB.